# Visual Basic 6.0 Login Form

Tags: vb6, oracle10g

Im having a trouble in creating a login form. My form is connected to my ora10g database. The username is in a combobox so that the user can login easily. Is there anyone can help me why everytime I choose a username in the combo box and type a correct password for that username it always show the msgbox"Username is invalid". Thank you for your help guys!

Here is my code for the OK button:

```
    Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
    cnn.Open " provider = MSDAORA; user id = System; password = Estacio;"
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open "Select * From Admin Where Username = '" & Combo1.Text & "'", cnn
    If rs.RecordCount < 1 Then
    MsgBox "Username is Invalid. Please try again.", vbInformation
    Combo1.SetFocus
    Else
    If txtPassword.Text = rs!Password Then
    Timer1.Enabled = True
    ProgressBar1.Visible = True
    Else
    MsgBox "Password is Invalid. Please try again.", vbInformation
    txtPassword.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
    End If
    End If
    Set rs = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Comment: Don't rely on the RecordCount property. Try checking that rs.EOF = False instead. If that doesn't work, run the query on Oracle and make sure you are returning a record there.

Comment: Thanks for the help dude. I decided to delete the line 7-10 since my combo box is connected to database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Dim cn As OracleConnection = New OracleConnection("Data Source=xe;User ID=hr;password=hr;Unicode=True")
    Dim cmd As OracleCommand
    Dim dr As OracleDataReader
cmd .Connection = cn
            cmd .CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Admin WHERE username = @username AND password = @password"
            cn.Open()
          cmd .Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@username", Combo1.Text))
            cmd .Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@password", txtPassword.Text))
 If cmd .ExecuteScalar = 1 Then
                MsgBox("Successful Login")

            Else
                MsgBox("Try Again")
            End If
```

try this ...I hope it work